# LyX adds unwanted sorting key into index entries

Tags: lyx, indexing, polyglossia, hebrew

I am writing a document in the memoir document class, using LyX.

The document main language is Hebrew (minority of the document is in English), and I use polyglossia and XeTeX to handle the languages, so that my doc preamble is

```
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,10pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\setotherlanguage{english}
```

When I insert an English index entry into my document, instead of creating the `tex` command

```
\index{Dirac, Paul}
```

LyX creates something else.

With [image] I get

```
\index{Dirac, Paul@\textenglish[variant=american]{Dirac, Paul}}
```

and with [image] I get

```
\textenglish[variant=american]{\index{Dirac, Paul}}
```

(The blue understroke indicates foreign language)

Turns out that the more correct usage is the later, but the former is a bit more comfortable to use.

Can I change the former usage to be without this extra `@` and stating the entry twice? A colleague of mine has told me that this behavior of LyX is not the same on his machine.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, I suggest you send a minimal example .lyx file to the lyx-users mailing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a discussion with the LyX team in the mailing list, it turns out that this is overall correct. The string before the `@` is a sorting key. The second example shown in the question is the closest to the input a LaTeX user would have done.

You can bypass this behavior by inserting the following into a local layout of the document (or by creating a module file with this code and "installing" it in the layouts directory of LyX):

```
Format 60
InsetLayout Flex:index
    LyXType        custom
    LabelString    "Index"
    LatexType      Command
    LatexName      index
    Decoration     classic
End
```

Then insert an index entry with Insert -> Custom Insets, then choose index.

The tex output with this method is

```
\index{\textenglish[variant=american]{Dirac, Paul}}
```

For more information about custom insets, see the [LyX customization manual](https://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/Manuals#Customization).